# ActivityTransition new API

Tags: android, google-awareness

Google released new api to identify ActivityTransition(https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityTransition). Is there any example how to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it in developer official site developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/transitions.html